# javascript code to be done without self invoking function

Tags: javascript

Following code works fine. What i want is to do the same thing but without any self invoking function

```
<html>
<body>
<input type='button' value='click' onclick="addLinks()">
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
function addLinks ()
{ 
 for (var i=0, link; i<5; i++)
  { 
    link = document.createElement("a"); 
    link.innerHTML = "Link " + i;
    link.onclick = (function (x) //self invoking function
      {
        return function()
           { 
               alert(x); 
           };
      })(i);
document.body.appendChild(link); } }
</script>
```

Comment: I can think of at least three different ways, but none of them are better then the IIFE. What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: nothing is wrong with what i have. i Just wanna do it without the self invoking function. that is the task!

Comment: and by the way read my code. i have used IIFE. i want to do without using it!

Comment: Reading your code would be easier if the indentation wasn't totally messed up, you know.

Comment: thnx for the suggestion, will take care from next time

Comment: @kingshukbasak: *"and by the way read my code"* 1. That reads fairly rude. I'm sure you didn't mean it that way. 2. What makes you think Quentin, who's a *really useful, clued-in person*, didn't read it?

Comment: my apologies. new to stack overflow. sorry !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid creating the throwaway IIFE by splitting it out:

```
function addLinks() {
    for (var i = 0, link; i < 5; i++) {
        link = document.createElement("a");
        link.innerHTML = "Link " + i;
        link.onclick = buildHandler(i);
        document.body.appendChild(link);
    }

    function buildHandler(x) {
        return function() {
            alert(x);
        };
    }
}
```

But we can do better than that: How about using just *one* handler function for all the links?

```
function addLinks() {
    for (var i = 0, link; i < 5; i++) {
        link = document.createElement("a");
        link.innerHTML = "Link " + i;
        link.setAttribute("data-x", i);
        link.onclick = handler;
        document.body.appendChild(link);
    }

    function handler() {
        alert(this.getAttribute("data-x"));
    }
}
```

That only works for strings or things you can reasonably convert to/from strings, of course.

If you're okay with expando properties, we can go beyond strings:

```
function addLinks() {
    for (var i = 0, link; i < 5; i++) {
        link = document.createElement("a");
        link.innerHTML = "Link " + i;
        link.__x__ = i;
        link.onclick = handler;
        document.body.appendChild(link);
    }

    function handler() {
        alert(this.__x__);
    }
}
```

jQuery uses an expando for some of what it does, so we know they work well cross-browser. If you search you'll find arguments against them as well. I shy away.

Or we can use `Function#bind`:

```
function addLinks() {
    for (var i = 0, link; i < 5; i++) {
        link = document.createElement("a");
        link.innerHTML = "Link " + i;
        link.onclick = handler.bind(link, i);
        document.body.appendChild(link);
    }

    function handler(x) {
        alert(x);
    }
}
```

---

Side note: I advocate using `addEventListener` (`attachEvent` on obsolete IE) rather than `onclick`, as a general practice. E.g. for that last example:

```
link.addEventListener("click", handler.bind(link, i), false);
```